# Rxjs best practices: Execute a backend call if a condition is met

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working in a feature of an angular project.
We have a /create component that renders a serie of inputs and dropdowns so the user can create a given object.

I want to reutilize that component to create a /edit:id component, so I can (no surprise here) edit that given object. All Inputs and dropdowns should be filled with the data of that object.

I have the following code:

Somewhere over the HTML I have a `(click)=onClick(id)` and inside the method `onClick(id)` I do the redirection to the /edit route.

Implement the new route in the `app-routing.module`. I.E:

```
{ path: 'edit/:id', component: createComponent }
```

and inside the OnInit hook of the `createComponent`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params
        .subscribe(id => console.log(id)); //this returns the given id edit/:id
```

So, if I'm in `/edit/:id` I get the Id, and if i'm in the original `/create` I got an empty object.

So I want to create the following logic:

```
    If the object that the observable emits is a blank object, im on /create thus I should do nothing --END
    If the object that the observable emits has a id property, im on a /edit
        I should call a service method that returns a second observable, this method triggers an HTTP GET call to the server to get the data of the object with id
            Subscribe to the result of that service method and set the result object in a property in my component
```

Rxjs is not my strongest suit, and I can't decide wich rxjs operator should I use to this given use case. My first implementation to achieve this involves a nested subscription but this doesn't seems the right approach. Can anyone send some pointers over this?

This is my code so far:

```js
    this.activatedRoute.params
      .pipe(
        map(params => Object.keys(params).length == 0 ? "" : params.id ), 
//check if the object is empty if so, return and empty string. Oterwise return the id
        switchMap(id=> id !== "" ? this.service.makeHttpCall(id): never())
//make the backend http call if id is not empty
      ).subscribe(result => 
        {
         console.log(result)
        });
```

This somehow works, but I would like to know if this is the best approach to perform this task.
Thanks

I ended up implementing a resolver as `Pankaj Parkar` told and the result is something along this lines:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) : Observable<any> 
    
    ObservableA
      .pipe(
        map(something => return something),
        switchMap(something => {
            return ObservableB
            .pipe(
              map(something => return something)
          } 
        }),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is okay, but I would suggest you to write Route Resolver and move this logic up there.

**Resolver**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class EntityResolver implements Resolve<Entity> {
  constructor(private service: HttpService) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    const id = Object.keys(route.params).length == 0 ? "" : route.params.id );
    return this.service.makeHttpCall(id): never();
  }
}
```

**Route**

```
{ 
   path: 'edit/:id',
   component: createComponent ,
   resolve: { hero: HeroResolver }
}
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.data);
}
```

This solution address below things.

1. Before route component is loaded it make sure the resolver data made available
2. Component don't need to have an extra logic for create and edit behavior.